# Changing Character strings to numeric in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert column variables from the characters "Strong", "Semi-Strong", "weak" and very weak" to numeric values (1-4) based on the strengths so I can run a regression on the variables.
I am fairly new to R, and want 1 to indicate "very weak" and so on..

Thx for help!

Comment: as.numeric(as.factor(column, levels=c("very weak", "weak", "semi-strong", "strong")))

Comment: Besides the technical answer, I am not sure whether you should do that. When you transform your character to a numeric, you are postolating that there is a linear relationship between the levels. That is we could set strength to `2.5` which corresponds to what? "Half semi-string"? "Almost weak"? I would rather code them as factors. Then the parameters encode as the differnce between the first level ("strong") and the respective level, e.g. parameter for "weak" is the difference between "strong" and "weak"